# How to use custom HTML in wp_nav_menu in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, menu

My nav-menu template is:

```
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span data-hover="my-text">item1</span> 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to use this mark-up in wp-nav-menu in WordPress?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I edit code's answer of Hareesh Sivasubramanian and get the answer:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;


        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span data-hover="';
        $item_output .= apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output .= '">';
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</span></a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't a custom class neither is a template. You should declare the style you want inside a `<style>` tag or in a css file and then link that file to your html.

On css you use selectors to define what elements will have they style changed. Class selectors start with a dot `.`, for example `.navbar-nav`.

Extended example:

```
.navbar-nav{
    background-color:black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Your html code should go directly in the page you want it to be. Unless you're using some template engine that can import an html template, reusing common code that way.

Comment: my problem isnt css, i want use <span data-hover="item1"> tag in nav-menu. what is it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class) Class. Edit the HTML as needed.

Also make sure you edit the template which calls the `wp_nav_menu` function and add the `walker` parameter to it.

Add this to your `functions.php` file.

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;


        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span data-hover="my-text">';
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</span></a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }


}
```

And add `'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu` to the `wp_nav_menu` function that calls your menu.

Comment: Very Thanks! How to put the "my-text" word of the text-items. Example: <span data-hover="item1">item1</span>